# Create an array using sapply and particular arrays in a data frame

Tags: r, sapply

I want to create an array using `sapply` in R. But I am using 3 vectors in a data frame. For instance, I want to generate `x(i)=0` if `a(i) +b(i)+c(i)==0` ,where `a`, `b` and `c` are vectors from the data frame. Is this possible with `sapply` or `mapply`?

Comment: What do you want `x[i]` to be when the condition is not met?

Comment: If the condition is not met, x(i) equals to one. But this is really not key. I pre-set the whole vector to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `x` is pre-initialized to be all ones, and `df` is the data frame that contains `a`, `b`, and `c`, then a simple solution is:

```
x[with(df, a + b + c == 0)] <- 0
```

Here we generate an index vector that contains `TRUE` whenever the desired condition is met (`a + b + c == 0`), and then use that to replace those values with zero in `x`.  With the data frame generated by @Shambho, we get:

```
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `with` function. It works. But my question remains. Can sapply or mapply work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility:

```
set.seed(10)
vex <- data.frame(
  a=sample(-1:1,size=10,replace=T),
  b=sample(-1:1,size=10,replace=T),
  c=sample(-1:1,size=10,replace=T)
  )
vex

x <- sapply(1:nrow(vex), function(i) ifelse(sum(vex[i,]==0),0,1))
x
```

Since `vex` is a `data.frame` with columns `a`, `b` and `c`, `sum(vex[i,])` will add the i'th row, and is equivalent to `a[i]+b[i]+c[i]`!

Comment: I don't understand your code. I am new to R. Could you explain what you did in the `sapply` function. And I am not using the whole data frame, just few vectors in the data frame. I don't see how could I select these vectors in your code.

Comment: Oh well... If you just implemented the code, I think it would have made sense. Your specific requirement was to use "sapply or mapply" hence this implementation. Otherwise there are many diffenent ways of doing this (as mentioned by @BrodieG !!)